# Are there any studies regarding nicotine excretion through the skin?

Tags: smoking, nicotine, skin-absorption

Nicotine can easily be absorbed through the skin. There are tons of studies on that, and the fact that e.g. trans-dermal patches work.
A pediatrician recently mentioned that smokers also excreted nicotine through their skin and would thus pose a danger to infants. While the fact that particles from smoke tend to linger in clothes seems to be well established, the claim that nicotine was excreted through the skin sounded a bit dubious to me. I couldn't find any research on this.
Do you know any studies regarding this topic?

Comment: A little research would be helpful, and is a requirement here. Who is the pediatrician who said that? A link would be good.